# Android Layout Changes

Tags: android, layout

I'm arranging elements on a layout, but if I use Linear Layout, everything lines up along the left. If I set `gravity` of some elements to be `"center"`, for example, some texts, then on a phone, it looks ok. But if is a pad, then the whole view lies on the left side leaving large area on the right.

So how can I make the view in the center on any devices?

The second question is: If I set the text to be longer, then some words disappear (since they are out of the layout). How can I make the words lie in the center with several lines if necessary instead of being just one really long line and some part outside the view?

[image: problem_layout.png]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:ems="10" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/first_radiogroup"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/1_1"
            android:text="1_1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/1_2"
            android:text="1_2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/1_3"
            android:text="1_3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firsttext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="1.5"
        android:text="please choose from the below:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="serif" 
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/secon_radiogroup"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/2_1"
            android:text="2_1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/2_2"
            android:text="2_2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/2_3"
            android:text="2_3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="1.5"
        android:text="please choose from the below:"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/final"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:text="final" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="4" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="174dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="5" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="6" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="166dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: you should better add code of your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make different layout file for different screen size.
here below link may help you

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html

Comment: Thanks for giving the link. I didn't know this before.

Comment: Do you know how to set the text in the middle of screen?